# Dual Booting with GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, grub, bootloader

I currently have Ubuntu and XP as dual boot using GRUB. The Ubuntu version is old and I want to blow it away and do a fresh install of a modern version.

I want to keep XP and GRUB. It seems every article assumes you want to remove both! Does anyone know how to remove the current version of Ubuntu and then install another without removing GRUB and breaking things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern Desktop Linux installs are smart enough to keep Windows partitions and automatically add them to the Grub boot script.  I haven't used newer Ubuntu versions, but I know openSUSE does this.

That said, I would attempt to run through a newer Ubuntu install and see what it says when the auto-partitioning comes up.  See if it sets up a mount point for the current Windows installation.

Comment: Thanks, so if I just run the install for the new ubuntu it will know what to do? This system is older and I do worry about space, so will it remove one of the ubuntu versions?

Comment: I just edited my original statement to add a comment about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite the old version of Ubuntu using the partitioner available in the setup, it should detect Windows XP with `os-prober` and install GRUB fresh into your MBR.

Comment: This is correct as well, the other guy was first is why I marked it as answer. Thanks